# Сортировка двойного массива

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Подскажите, как отсортировать двойной массив массив? типа array(array("Один", 1, 15), array("Два", 2, 17)...). Нужна сортировка по разным элементам массива.

Comment: Что именно хотите получить? Отсортировать массив по одному из элементов вложенного массива? Как учитываются ваши разные элементы массива в сортировке? По ним идет сравнение по каким то правилам, типо хеша массива?

в общем ваш вопрос порождает миллионы других вопросов и хорошо развивает телепатию )

Comment: Да. Отсортировать массив по одному из элементов вложенного массива.
Собственно вопрос, существуют ли подходящие функции или проще самому написать сортировку?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел usort(), которая решает все проблемы.